# Array of strings coordinates into array of integers in python

Tags: python, numpy, integer

I have an array of strings coordinates of the way:

```
A = [ '(0.0),(3,3),(5,8)', '(1,2),(5,8),(8,9),(20,6)' , '(45,6),(91,5),(86,4)' , '(100,2),(105,8),(53,6)']
```

I need to convert these into integers, so far i've tried to convert it by using `int(A`) or `float(A)`.

By using `int()` i get this error:

```
"ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '(0, 0),(3, 0),(6, 0),(6, 5),(13, 0),(25, 5),(27, 5),(29, 5),(30, 0),(35, 5),(37, 5),(38, 5),(45, 0),(52, 0),(53, 5),(56, 0),(58, 0),(60, 0),(60, 5),(61, 5),(66, 0),(66, 5),(73, 0),(74, 0),(75, 5),(76"
```

Comment: It isn't clear what the intended output is. Please elaborate.

Comment: the full array is (51,) in shape, each one of the 51 elements is a string of 2d coordinates (x,y). The total amount of elements in unknown. The idea is to have as an output each of the arrays of coordinates converted into integers.

Comment: What about `[ast.literal_eval(i) for i in A]`?

Comment: That initial `(0.0)` doesn't follow the pattern of the rest. Is that supposed to be `(0,0)`?

Comment: @JohnColeman, it is the example of how characteristics of the array, it is too big to put here, doesn´t follow any pattern at the moment

Comment: @jsp The point is that `(0.0)` is a tuple containing a single float, but everything else in your data seems to be a tuple containing a pair of ints (after you translate from a string). I think that your `A` in the question contains a typo.

Comment: @JohnColeman let me give you the exact component. This is the first element of the array
A[0] = '(0, 0),(3, 0),(6, 0),(6, 5),(13, 0),(25, 5),(27, 5),(29, 5),(30, 0),(35, 5),(37, 5),(38, 5),(45, 0),(52, 0),(53, 5),(56, 0),(58, 0),(60, 0),(60, 5),(61, 5),(66, 0),(66, 5),(73, 0),(74, 0),(75, 5),(76, 0),(81, 0),(89, 0),(91, 5),(94, 5),(96, 0),(100, 0),(100, 5),(103, 0)'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment on the question, one way could be to use a safe `eval` method such as `ast.literal_eval` to parse the strings into tuples.

Assuming `(0.0)` should be `(0,0)`:

```
import ast

[ast.literal_eval(i) for i in A]
```

Output:

```
[((0, 0), (3, 3), (5, 8)),
 ((1, 2), (5, 8), (8, 9), (20, 6)),
 ((45, 6), (91, 5), (86, 4)),
 ((100, 2), (105, 8), (53, 6))]
```

Answer (score 1):

(Assuming 0.0 is a typo)

As suggested by S3DEV, a fast way to do it would be to use some type of `eval()`, but it's not recommended.

```
[list(eval(i)) for i in A]
```

```
[[(0, 0), (3, 3), (5, 8)],
 [(1, 2), (5, 8), (8, 9), (20, 6)],
 [(45, 6), (91, 5), (86, 4)],
 [(100, 2), (105, 8), (53, 6)]]
```

---

Comparison of `eval` vs `literal_eval`

1. `eval:` This is very powerful, but is also very dangerous if you accept strings to evaluate from untrusted input. Imagine using eval on `rm -rf /`!!
2. `ast.literal_eval:` Only operates on a limited set of python literal structures. This makes if more secure.

In your case since your inputs are strings of coordinates (ensure this!) then both methods are equally safe/unsafe for you.

Comment: Thanks. Correction: `ast.literal_eval`. It's a safer option to regular `eval`.  And please let me post my own answers.  Cheers mate.

Comment: @S3DEV, agreed. Let me update that as well.

Comment: It might be better to use `ast.literal_eval(','.join(A))` to simultaneously flatten the data into simple pairs (which OP seems to want).

Comment: I don't mean to be rude, but I feel you misunderstood my comment.  I appreciate the attribution, however would appreciate it more if you'd let me post my own answers and delete this one. Thank you.

Comment: Oh, i believe we misunderstood each other then :). I was already posting about using `eval()` as a possible solution and decided to mention your suggestion in the comments as part of it. I didnt realise you would want to post your own answer since you had just commented without posting any answer. Have reverted back to my original answer. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

How about a regex solution? IMHO a bit cleaner, no need for using `eval`.

```
import re

A = ['(0,0),(3,3),(5,8)', '(1,2),(5,8),(8,9),(20,6)', '(45,6),(91,5),(86,4)', '(100,2),(105,8),(53,6)']
pattern = re.compile(r'\((\d+), *(\d+)\)')
[[(int(x), int(y)) for x, y in position] for position in [re.findall(pattern, group) for group in A]]

>> [[(0, 0), (3, 3), (5, 8)],
    [(1, 2), (5, 8), (8, 9), (20, 6)],
    [(45, 6), (91, 5), (86, 4)],
    [(100, 2), (105, 8), (53, 6)]]
```